# is it right documentation of method documentation of java?

Tags: javadoc

is it right documentation of method documentation of java?
my part of code is below. there is no parameter but have returns. only local variables.

```
/**
 *This method prompts user to enter the how many numbers user is going to test.
 *
 *@return     The validated value based on parameter.
 */

public static int getNum()
{
    int t;
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("How many numbers would you like to test? ");
    t=input.nextInt();

    while (validateNum(t))
    {
        System.out.print("How many numbers would you like to test? ");
        t=input.nextInt();
    }

    return t;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Javadoc for methods should *not* start with the words "This method" - that is *implied* at the start of every method description.

Similarly, when documenting classes one assumes that the words "This class" appears before your comments.

Also, you are describing the implementation (asking the user), but the implementation should be free to get it any way it wants, for example reading it from a file or returning a constant.

Here's something more suitable:

```
/**
 * Return how many numbers user is going to test.
 *
 * @return The number of numbers to be tested
 */
```